# Which is the best code generator and folder structure for MEAN Stack developing?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Now I am using **express-generator** for mean stack developing. It's folder structure is created for server side **(NodeJS)** folder structure.

And I create Angular controllers, services, routes, config files inside the **public folder**. Is it a correct way to mean stack structure?.

How to create client-side **(AngularJS)** folder structure or Both **(AngularJS and NodeJS)**?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-mean

Answer (score 0):

It's one way to create stack structure.
Else you could use some tools such as gulp or grunt that will allow you to automatize your tasks such as launch the server by taking into account your server and your client (more clear).

Another way is to create an API (back end with node.js) and use some http call in angular to get the data from the server. So that you will have two distincts repository, one for the server and one for the client.

Else you could have this tools:
http://yeoman.io/ or http://mean.io/ can generate some specific structure for your application.

PS: There are some boilerplate on internet that could show you several way to structure your app, look at them and you could find a structure that will satisfy you.

Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Thank You Sir. But what is the advantages and difference b/w. create folder structure with code generator and dynamically create?.

Comment: By using a code generator, you will need to follow their structure (depends if you accept this specific structure or not, if you like it or not) but you will have all the basics to start a new project efficiently and quicker without misconceptions because a lot of people correct it and you do not need to redo anything from zero.

Comment: By doing it dynamically by yourself, you will have to define your own structure, you can configure it as you want and it will be i guess better to maintain, improve or add new module. You will learn more things about the language and his specificities. You will be more free in your development.

With both of them you will have the same possibilites but it will take a little more time if you do not use a generator.
After that's my point of view, maybe other will think differently.

The best to do is to try both of them and work with the one you prefer (to be more productive ^^).